# How to know property value if in runtime I have reference to bean instance and property name?

Tags: java, reflection, field

I have following bean

```
class MyBean{
  Date myDate;
  String anotherProperty;
  ...
}
```

and following method:

```
public static Date getDateField(MyBean instance, String propertyName){
   ...
}
```

I want to invoke following method like this:

```
getDateField(myBeanInstance, "myDate")
```

I am feeling that it is possible to achieve but I have not ideas how to realize `getDateField` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know name of property, you can create instance of `java.beans.PropertyDescriptor`.

```
new PropertyDescriptor(propertyName, myBeanInstance.getClass())
```

or if you already know that type of `myBeanInstance` is `MyBean` then

```
new PropertyDescriptor(propertyName, MyBean.class)
```

Then you can access its getter `Method` via `getReadMethod()` and `invoke` it on `instance.`

So your code can look like

```
Object value = new PropertyDescriptor(propertyName, instance.getClass())
                    .getReadMethod()
                    .invoke(instance);
```

Comment: I think that getClass returns same value for all instances

Comment: @gstackoverflow in that case you can use this class literal directly like `new PropertyDescriptor(propertyName, MyBean.class)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Reflection to access the field value like:

```
Class  aClass = MyBean.class
Field field = aClass.getField("myDate");
Object value = field.get(myBeanInstance);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the two values you passed in to use `reflection` to get the value. To get the `Field` you must call `getDeclaredField` (since it's private, otherwise we'd use `getField`) on your `Class` (which can be get by running `getClass` on your instance.

```
Field f = instance.getClass().getDeclaredField(propertyName);
```

Because you have no access modifier you're stuck with the default access which is `package-private` so you must then make the field accessible to the outside world which can be done by calling `setAccessible`

```
f.setAccessible(true);
```

Then you can get your value by calling `get` on your `Field`!

```
Date d = (Date) f.get(instance);
```

You should read up on Reflection at the [Java Tutorials Website](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29), both will significantly improve your knowledge and you'll be able to figure it out on your own next time!